# Cordova iOS 3.7.0 Issue - [__NSCFString JSONObject]: unrecognized selector

Tags: cordova

My app works fine with Cordova iOS 3.6.3. However with iOS 3.7.0 I get error and app does not start. This is the only information I see in the logs in the emulator:

```
2014-11-23 23:55:21.149 App[68461:5278465] -[__NSCFString JSONObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x122db42b0
2014-11-23 23:55:21.151 App 68461:5278465] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[__NSCFString JSONObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x122db42b0
2014-11-23 23:55:21.176 App[68461:5278465] -[__NSCFString JSONObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x122db4278
2014-11-23 23:55:21.176 App 68461:5278465] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[__NSCFString JSONObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x122db4278
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does the project have the correct cordova.js (3.7.0) file? How did you update from 3.6.3 to 3.7?

Comment: It does have correct cordova.js. The issue in my case was related to parse.com plugin requiring Facebook SDK. I was able to remove -ObjC in previous versions. Now doing that is breaking some other libraries that might be needed in 3.7.0. I have added Facebook SDK to work around this.

Answer (score 21):

This is a problem if you remove the `-ObjC` linker switch. The libCordova.a library specifies some categories on NSString which will not get loaded if `-ObjC` is removed.

A work around is to remove libCordova.a from the linked frameworks and add this to the Other Linker Flags build setting:

`-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libCordova.a`

This will cause all symbols (including the categories) in libCordova.a to be loaded while keeping `-ObjC` off.